# Difference between Scaffold-DbContext and dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, db-first

I see that there are to way how to scaffold entities and db context in Entity Framework Core 2.0.

1. using `Scaffold-DbContext`
2. using `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`

Why there are two tools and what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Scaffold-DbContext` runs in Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager Console (PMC) and has better VS integration--opens files and infers the startup project.

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` is a general command-line interface that can run outside of Visual Studio (and Windows).

Otherwise, they execute the exact same logic.